# How to run code only after query has finished?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
var userFound = false;
let sql = `SELECT box_id, cubby_id, comport, deliveredToUser
           FROM recipients
           WHERE package_password = ?`;
connection.query(sql, [req.session.sessionUserPackagePassword],
                      function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err) {
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            // Make the comparaison case insensitive
            if ((rows[i].deliveredToUser).toLowerCase() == `no`) {
                userFound = true;
                console.log(userFound);
                var comport = rows[i].comport;
                var command = "open" + rows[i].cubby_id;
                var commandClose = "close" + rows[i].cubby_id;
                var commandStatus = "status" + rows[i].cubby_id;
                console.log(command);
                console.log(comport);
                var options = {
                    scriptPath: 'python/scripts',
                    // pass arguments to the script here    
                    args: [command, comport, commandClose, commandStatus] 
                };
                PythonShell.run('controlLock.py', options, function(err, results) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.render('errorConnection', {});
                    }
                    console.log('results: %j', results);
                });
            }
        }
        console.log(userFound);
        // If the query fails to execute
    } else {
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
        res.render('errorConnection', {});
    }
});
connection.end();
if (!userFound) {
    //
    res.render('pickup/errorAlreadyDelivered', {});
    connection.end();
}
```

I would want this part at the end to be run only once the query has finished:

```
if (!userFound) {
    //
    res.render('pickup/errorAlreadyDelivered', {});
    connection.end();
}
console.log("connection ended " + userFound);
```

I placed a `console.log` outside of the query and at the bottom and despite the query value changing to `true` it prints out `false` first, and comes out first because the `console.log` didn't wait until the query has finish to be able to store the value.

Comment: Yes but i need the if (!userFound)statement to be outside because theres code below, and i would want to run an else statement to run the below code if that condition is not met

Comment: You have to put it in the callback function, all of it, including "the code below". Or, create another function that has "the code below", and call it from within the query callback. Once you get results asynchronously, you need to continue doing things with it asynchronously. You cannot expect it to magically become available synchronously.

Comment: but then how would grab a value inside of a function and replace it with a value outside of the function?

Comment: Nothing outside. Everything that depends on the asunc result must be executed async.